# Node.js: Function not awaiting for a promise

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

I'm having an issue with a function not awaiting for a promise.

I have a route with a post method, that pushes the body to the controller.
The controller, will then send it to the middleware to actually process the save to a MongoDB.
The middleware will return the the promised object back to the controller.

The controller is finishing with out awaiting the completion of the middleware.

The middleware is async, and the controller has an await and then a .then even following further.
Thoughts?

Controller

```
export async function createPlayer(req,res) {
    //creates a Player in the database
    try {
        let results = '';
        results = await PlayerFunction.createPlayer(req.body)
        .then(console.log(results))
        .then(res.status(200).send(results))
  
    } catch (error) {
        log_error('Errored trying to create Player in controller.', error);
        res.status(404).send('Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.');
    }

};
```

Middleware

```
export async function createPlayer(req_body) {
    //creates a Player in the database
    try {
        //set new player object
        let new_Player = new Player(req_body);
        new_Player.save((error) => {
            if (error) {
                log_error('Trying to create a Player.', error)
                return { success: 'error', body: 'Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.' };
            } else {
                console.log(new_Player);
                return { success: true, body: new_Player };
            };
        });
    } catch (error) {
        log_error('Errored trying to create a player.', error);
        return { success: 'error', body: 'Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.' };
    }
};
```

I tried to use .then promises to catch the returned results from the middleware and then return the results to the user.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is that the .save((error) => function doesn't follow the await made by the call it self. If you remove the error handling on the Save and rely on the catch in the overall try catch it will follow the await.

Controller:

```
export async function createPlayer(req,res) {
//creates a Player in the database
try {
    
    res.status(200).send(await PlayerFunction.createPlayer(req.body));

} catch (error) {
    log_error('Errored trying to create Player in controller.', error);
    res.status(404).send('Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.');
}
```

};

Middlewear

```
export async function createPlayer(req_body) {
//creates a Player in the database
try {
    let new_Player = new Player(req_body);
    await new_Player.save();
    return { success: true, body: new_Player };

} catch (error) {
    log_error('Errored trying to create a player.', error);
    return { success: 'error', body: 'Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.' };
}
```

};

Answer (score -1):

In the `async` function needs to return promise-based value.

A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async function, or rejected with an exception thrown from, or uncaught within, the async function.

So in your middleware `createPlayer()` needs to return Promise-based value.

```
export async function createPlayer(req_body) {
    //creates a Player in the database
    try {
        //set new player object
        let new_Player = new Player(req_body);
        new_Player.save((error) => {
            if (error) {
                log_error('Trying to create a Player.', error)
                return Promise.reject(JSON.stringify({ success: 'error', body: 'Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.' }));
            } else {
                console.log(new_Player);
                return Promise.resolve(JSON.stringify({ success: true, body: new_Player }));
            };
        });
    } catch (error) {
        log_error('Errored trying to create a player.', error);
        return Promise.reject(JSON.stringify({ success: 'error', body: 'Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.' }));
    }
};
```

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: Returning from callbacks is futile.